# What is the difference between 发货，出货 and 交货？

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between 发货, 出货, and 交货?

Comment: seems like asking for the difference between (1)send out goods; deliver goods; delivery; [经] consignment (2)shipment; [经] clear; deliver from godown (3)delivery; consignment; deliver the goods (see iciba),交货 most common, taken literally 1,2 evidently only say "send/ship out" whereas 3 means "deliver"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

出货: produce goods

发货: ship goods

交货: deliver goods